# Next.js 14 in Docker container, cannot access to localhost when running

Tags: docker, next.js, dockerfile, next.js13

Help me please with running my Next.js 14 app with docker.
I attach my simple Dockerfile code.
In a fact, image builds ok and when I run container, logs seems like regular next app running, but localhost in browser doesn't available, like app isn't running.

```
FROM node:18-alpine

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm ci

COPY . .

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

UPDATED:

This solved, it was been issue with ports setup

but now it has another issue - I don't see any styles in my app, just markup
And for any request it has the same logs. e.g for oauth request:

```
oauth action authorize error:  TypeError: fetch failed
     at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11730:11)
     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
   cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9900
       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
       at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:128:17) {
     errno: -111,
     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: '127.0.0.1',
     port: 9900
   }
 }
```

and for any another req it has the same error reason
My API running in docker container too, but it working good for Next app running without container
Anybody got the same issue ?

Comment: Try `docker ps` to see the exported ports. If you don't export any, you need to use the IP address that is assigned to the Docker container.

Comment: this is PORTS column for this running container:
`0.0.0.0:3003->3003/tcp`

Comment: did you find out ?

Comment: Oh, yes, I was created internal docker network for communication between containers